# Run Powershell script that uses -List (parameter) with alternate credentials that

Tags: powershell, automation, parameter-passing, invoke-command, start-process

I was struggling to get this simple (?) function working today.

I have a PowerShell script that reads computer names from a txt-based file. It works fine when run from a PowerShell session by the following one-liner:

```
./"Server Health Check.ps1" -List One-off.txt
```

As you can see, it's got a long file name, so it's wrapped with quotes.

However, I'm building a PowerShell GUI form with radio boxes that will pass on a choice for a text file that will be used to a call the script. Trick is, the script needs to be run with **alternate** admin account, and i'm not clear how to make that work.

For another script I've got that doesn't use I know i can use something along the lines of the following, this uses the old DOS "runas", however, it doesn't work with the -list function.

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {runas.exe /user:domain\$Env:Username"admin" "powershell.exe -file \"\\Server\c$\LONG FOLDER\Server Health Check.PS1""}
```

So, in a nutshell, how do get a script to launch with alternate credentials  that reads a parameter (-List) from the command line? I'm also keen to preserve my directory structure, which includes folders with spaces. The script is titled: **"Server health check.ps1"**

The last thing I tried was the following

```
$ScriptPath = "C:\SCRIPTS FOLDER\Server Health Check.ps1"
$ArgList = "-List C:\SCRIPTS FOLDER\One-off.txt"
Invoke-Command -filepath $ScriptPath -Credential DragonBallDomain\$Env:UserName"Admin"  -ArgumentList $ArgList
```

The result was the following message:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

I'm almost certain this is do-able by invoke-command or start-process, it's just a matter of getting the correct formatting? I'm probably missing a / or a ' or "" somewhere in my trials with start-process or invoke-command.

Any help appreciated!

**Update for April 30:**

I've tried some more to make this work, i'm close, but still not quite there.

```
$LongScriptPath = resolve-path Script.ps1
$LongFolderPath = \\UNC\PATH TO FOLDER\WITH LONG NAME\
 start-process -filepath powershell.exe -argumentlist " -file``"$($FilePath.path)`"" -cred DOMAIN\USERID -WorkingDirectory "$LongFolderPath"
```

Adding the -credential is what causes an error that states that the -file parameter is invalid. I'm sure there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: Completely rewritten after the requirements became clearer.</sup>

To **run a command *as a different* user *locally***, use `Start-Process -Credential ...`

That is what you've attempted in your update in principle, but there are problems with how you're passing parameters; try this instead:

```
$LongScriptPath = resolve-path Script.ps1
$LongFolderPath = '\\UNC\PATH TO FOLDER\WITH LONG NAME\'
start-process `
  powershell.exe `
  -ArgumentList '-file', $LongScriptPath, '-List', 'One-off.txt' `
  -Credential DOMAIN\USERID `
  -WorkingDirectory $LongFolderPath
```

- The key to making this work is to pass all parameters to pass to `powershell.exe` as an *array* via `Start-Process`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter, which means that the parameters must be `,`-separated.

  - Note how an array is always parsed in *expression* mode, which means that literal string elements such as `-file` and `-List` must be *quoted*.
  - It is important in general to understand the difference between PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes, *argument mode* and *expression mode*, and which is applied when - see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx
- Add `-Wait` to wait for the script to finish; `Start-Process` is *asynchronous* by default (all PS cmdlets named `Start-*` are).

  - Caveat: For commands invoked as a different user, you can only wait from an *elevated* prompt.
    If it isn't, the command will still execute, but will do so asynchronously, and you'll get an `Access denied` error message in the current console; in effect, `-Wait` is ignored.
- Only if *not* running as a different user: Add `-NoNewWindow -Wait` if you want to run the script in the *current* console window; `Start-Process` opens a new window by default for console applications such as `powershell.exe` and `cmd.exe`.

  - If you do run the command as a different user, `-NoNewWindow` is quietly ignored.

---

As for the original symptom and **why using `Invoke-Command` to run a command locally as a different user is ill-advised**:

- `Invoke-Command -Credential ...` requires that the `-ComputerName` parameter be specified too.

  - Run `Get-Help Invoke-Command` to see all parameter sets that involve the `-Credential` parameter. The OP's original command had only `-Credential`, but not `-ComputerName`, which caused PS to complain that no parameter set could be unambiguously identified.
- Once you use `-ComputerName`, PowerShell *remoting* is invariably used, even if you specify `.` - the *local* computer - as the only computer to target.

  - Using *remoting* has two implications:

    - Remoting is not available by default, and must be configured on the target computer (the local computer, in this case).
    - Using remoting requires invocation with *admin* privileges.

**In short:**

- While you *can* perform purely local invocations with `Invoke-Command`, you cannot do so *as another user*, because that invariably involves remoting.
- `Start-Process`, by contrast, solely exists to run commands *locally*, optionally as a different user.